# Can you swap "plus" with "aussi" without any practical difference here?

Tags: usage, adverbes

In conversation, I just said:

> En arrivant à l'aéroport, on est passés par je ne sais combien de contrôles de sécurité tous **plus** rigoureux les uns que les autres.

While I've personally never heard/seen "*aussi*" used in this specific construction, I wonder if you can also say:

> En arrivant à l'aéroport, on est passés par je ne sais combien de contrôles de sécurité tous **aussi** rigoureux les uns que les autres.

Leaving aside the difference in meaning between "*plus*" and "*aussi*" as a single word, is there no practical difference between the two constructions? Or does the use of "*aussi*" take away from the hyperbolic nature of the expression?

---

I mean, in contrast to instances where "peu" is thrown into the mix, in which case the use of "*plus*" is no longer an option:

> ... tous **aussi peu** justifiés les uns que les autres

Comment: in "tous aussi peu justifiés" the "aussi" is on "peu justifiés"; as you could say "tous aussi justifiés". That said, you could not use plus because "tous plus peu justifiés" would sound strange; you'd say "tous plus injustifié..."

Answer (score 3):

For me there is a little (subjective) difference between "plus" and "aussi"

> tous *aussi* rigoureux les uns que les autres

Mean that all checks perfectly follow the same strict protocol.

> tous *plus* rigoureux les uns que les autres

Mean that all check tries to be better than others.

In all case this mean that there is a high level of security.

Answer (score 2):

Using "plus" sounds to me that it is a bit more emphasized.

Both "plus" and "aussi" in that sentence would express that the security controls are very rigorous, however, telling me that:

> Le 1er aéroport a des contrôles de sécurité tous plus rigoureux les uns que les autres.

And

> Le 2nd aéroport a des contrôles de sécurité tous aussi rigoureux les uns que les autres

I would understand that both airports' security is excellent but I would say it is slightly better for the first one.

In conclusion, there's a little difference between these constructions and the "aussi" form doesn't remove the hyperbolic nature of the expression.